# Is it possible to render such table of contents with chapter number and chapter on separate line of toc?

Tags: table-of-contents

[image: Desired Table of Contents]

I am writing a college mini-thesis.The table of contents is pretty non-standard. How do I recreate this table of contents in LaTeX.
Even weirder requirements would be something like

Chapter I

1. Introduction

   1.1 *Apple*

   1.2 *Ball*

   1.3 *Cat*

Chapter II

2. Literature Review

   2.1 *What the apple?*

   2.2 *Frustrated atoms*

Is it possible to create this? I tried using titlesec package but couldn't do much.
I have this in my preamble for now.

```
\titleformat
{\chapter} % command
[display] % shape
{\bfseries\Large\itshape} % format
{CHAPTER \ \Roman{chapter}} % label
{0.5ex} % sep
{
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \vspace{1ex}
    \centering
} % before-code
[
\vspace{-0.5ex}%
\rule{\textwidth}{0.3pt}
] % after-code


\titleformat{\section}[wrap]
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}

\titlespacing{\section}{12pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you.

```
% chaptocprob.tex  SE 652705
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\\} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
\section{Alpha}
\chapter{Two}
\section{Beta}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please acknowledge if it does or does not do what you can use.

Comment: Thank you! 
What I want is :

Chapter I

1. Introduction

    1.1 Water Cycle

          1.1.1 Its Importance

I just want Roman numeral for the chapter but  for the sections and subsections I want Arabic numbering like 1.2.4 and not I.2.4

Comment: @SushilKhatri I tried to answer about the ToC, nothing about your weirder requirements. Are you sure you want those? A reader could get confused if they see a chapter designated as 4 but it is numbered as IV.